# QComboBox text renders as white/transparent when item is selected

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtstylesheets, qcombobox

I have a QComboBox in my program with 5 items + 1 blank (default) item. I implemented a stylesheet to make the background transparent when nothing is changed (i.e. when the item selected is the blank/default one) and light-green, when the item selected, is different. My problem is: when I select a different item, Qt renders the selected item color as white:

[image: Initial behaviour for the QComboBox element]

When I click on other elements of the application (buttons, the QDateEdit, etc), it renders the value black (expected behavior):

[image: Behaviour after interaction with other elements; expected normal behaviour of the QComboBox]

I don't know what I'm missing here. I tried to look for a solution or even a diagnosis of this problem in both StackOverflow and the Qt forums. For reference, my QComboBox's stylesheet is the following:

```
QComboBox#access_level[changed="false"]{
    background-color:"transparent";
}

QComboBox#access_level[changed="true"]{
    background-color:rgba(171, 246, 183, 50);
    color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

I also tried to remove the stylesheet and the problem persisted. Also, to implement the `changed` variable my code looks like the following:

```
class MassActionDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MassActionDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.dialog = Ui_MassActionDialog()
        self.dialog.setupUi(self)
        .
        .
        self.original_access_level = 60
        self.access_level = self.original_access_level
        self.dialog.access_level.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.on_access_level_change)

    def on_access_level_change(self, idx): 
        new_access_level = (idx + 1)*10
        if new_access_level == self.original_access_level:
            # we mark the "changed" property as false
            self.dialog.access_level.setProperty("changed", False)
        else:
            self.dialog.access_level.setProperty("changed", True)
        self.access_level = new_access_level
        # reload the stylesheet of the object
        self.dialog.access_level.style().unpolish(self.dialog.access_level)
        self.dialog.access_level.style().polish(self.dialog.access_level)
```

Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the output if you remove **all** custom styling? Maybe "white" is (set as) the default inactive color?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in QSS, just add `color` property to state with `changed="false"`, like:

```css
QComboBox#access_level[changed="false"]{
    background-color:"transparent";
    color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

QComboBox#access_level[changed="true"]{
    background-color:rgba(171, 246, 183, 50);
    color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

And one more thing - set `changed` property in `__init__` with your default value.